# qb.properties() method in node js api of marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I am not able to use qb.properties() method in node js api of marklogic.
code is as below

```
var marklogic = require('marklogic');
var ins = marklogic.createDatabaseClient({'host':'localhost','port':'7010','user':'admin','password':'admin',});
var qb = marklogic.queryBuilder;
ins.documents.query(
    qb.properties(
        qb.term("Akhilesh")))
            .result(function(matches) {
                 matches.forEach(function(match) {
                     console.log(match.uri);
                 });
            });
```

I was getting error like there is no function like qb.properties(), but in the node API developer guide qb.properties() function is described as properties-fragment- query.

Comment: Can you confirm your exact MarkLogic version as well as the Node.js Client API version that you're using please?

Comment: MarkLogic9 and recent version of Node.js client API

Comment: as @grtjn said it seems like a documentation bug. Can you try to run it with qb.propertiesFragment() method?

Comment: I tried but It's not working same as cts:document-fragment-query()

Comment: so are you after the document-fragment-query() or the properties-fragment-query()?

Answer (score 0):

According to the API docs it is `propertiesFragment` not `properties`:

http://docs.marklogic.com/jsdoc/queryBuilder.html#propertiesFragment

HTH!

Comment: yeah it was working but the definition of above query  was given  wrong in the following link  https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/search#id_48946